# ¿Cómo poder agregar elementos de manera dinámica con Vue?

Tags: vue.js

Estoy creando un módulo que va a mostrar un simple pichart, esto lo haré con [fusioncharts](https://www.fusioncharts.com/vue-js-charts?framework=vue), pero según su documentación, lo que hay que hacer, es lo siguiente:

```
<template>

    <div>

        <v-container id="chart-container">
            
            <v-row>

                <v-col cols="12">
                    
                    <v-card>

                        <fusioncharts :type="type" :width="width" :height="height" :dataformat="dataFormat" :dataSource="dataSource"></fusioncharts>

                    </v-card>

                </v-col>

            </v-row>

        </v-container >

    </div>

</template>

<script>

    import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

    const chartData = [{"label":"Agronomía, veterinaria y afines","value":22},{"label":"Bellas artes","value":6},{"label":"Ciencias de la educación","value":4},{"label":"Ciencias de la salud","value":3},{"label":"Ciencias sociales y humanas","value":4},{"label":"Economía, administración, contaduría y afines","value":0},{"label":"Ingeniería, arquitectura, urbanismo y afines","value":13},{"label":"Matemáticas y ciencias naturales","value":1}];

    const dataSource = {
        chart: {
            caption: "Artículos registrados por área de conocimiento",
            subcaption: "Cantidad de artículos registrados por área de conocimiento",
            showPercentValues: 1,
            theme: "fusion",
            exportEnabled: 1,
        },
        data: chartData
    };

    export default {

        name: 'Inicio',

        components: {

            //

        },

        data: () => ({

            "type": "pie2d",
            "renderAt": "chart-container",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "350",
            "dataFormat": "json",
            dataSource

        }),

        computed: {

            ...mapGetters(['ruta']),

        },

        mounted () {

            this.consultarDatos();

        },

        methods: {

            consultarDatos: function() {

                axios.post(this.ruta + 'archivo.php', { consultar:true }).then(response => {

                    this.chartData = response.data;

                });

            }

        }

    }

</script>
```

Claramente, esto no funciona y mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo acceder a esa constante y agregarle la consulta a la base de datos para que me muestre las estadísticas siempre actualizadas?

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente:

- chartData la asignas directamente con la respuesta de axios. Por tanto debe ser parte de `data`.
- dataSource es función de chartData, por tanto debe ser computada
- el resto de las configuraciones son estáticas y pueden quedar en `data`.

En el siguiente ejemplo reemplacé axios por una función cualquiera que devuelve una promesa, la cual luego de 1.5s se resuelve con la data.

```js
Vue.use(VueFusionCharts, FusionCharts);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const axios = {
    post: async(ruta, body) => {
      return new Promise(res => {
        setTimeout(res, 1500);
      }).then(() => {
        return {
          data: [{
              label: "Agronomía, veterinaria y afines",
              value: Math.random() * 25,
            },
            {
              label: "Bellas artes",
              value: Math.random() * 25
            },
            {
              label: "Ciencias de la educación",
              value: Math.random() * 25
            },
            {
              label: "Ciencias de la salud",
              value: Math.random() * 25
            }

          ]
        };

      });
    }
  };

  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    name: "App",
    data: () => {
      return {
        type: "pie2d",
        renderAt: "app",
        width: "100%",
        height: "200",
        dataFormat: "json",
        chartData: [],
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$nextTick().then(() => {
        this.consultarDatos();
      });
    },
    methods: {
      consultarDatos() {
        return axios.post('lala', {}).then(response => {
          return this.chartData = response.data;
        });
      },
    },
    computed: {
      datasource() {
        return {
          chart: {
            showPercentValues: 1,
            theme: "fusion"
          },
          data: this.chartData,
        };
      },
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fusioncharts@3.16.0/fusioncharts.js" integrity="sha256-azwzYuaWplz+4LUtZUl+xPgFubxm5u7fKC1s/2uRRNo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fusioncharts@3.16.0/fusioncharts.charts.js" integrity="sha256-BT5uprfxBMH9fGA8m1cozAOE7lsRcKkMbCwWzS5z7TU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-fusioncharts@3.1.0/dist/vue-fusioncharts.min.js" integrity="sha256-zvUfvl8V7TgL4lkCaYReBmSNbxTxwWzEECf3HBbAy34=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="app">
  <fusioncharts v-if="chartData.length" :type="type" :width="width" :height="height" :data-source="datasource"></fusioncharts>
  <div v-if="!chartData.length">Esperando datos</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Claro... Ahorita lo intento y te comento.